# Converting multiple same name into one single name using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to fetch the user name instead of multi user name but unfortunately, the single user name is not showing.

[image: user name]

**Controller**

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
    $date = explode(' - ', $request->date);
    $auth = Auth::user();
    $hourLog = Hourlog::with('project', 'user');
    if ($request->user) {
        $hourLog->whereIn("user_id", $request->user)->get();
    } else if ($auth->user_type == 1) {
        $hourLog->where("user_id", $auth->id);
    }
    if ($request->project) {
        $hourLog->whereIn("project_id", $request->project)->get();
    }
    $data = [
        "hourlogs"  => $hourLog->whereBetween('date', $date)
           ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
           ->orderBy('start_time', 'asc')
           ->get(),
            "date"=> $date,
    ];
    return view('cms.projectreport.projectreport-list', $data);
}
```

**html view**

```
@foreach($hourlogs  as  $hourlog)   
    <tr>
        <td>{{$hourlog->user->name}}</td>
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: As far as I can see you are retrieving hourlogs which repeats the name many times, do you want to show only one instance of each user?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy()` on your query with the user_id:

```
$data = [
      "hourlogs"  => $hourLog->whereBetween('date', $date)
                              ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                              ->orderBy('start_time', 'asc')
                              ->groupBy('user_id')
                              ->get(),
      "date"=> $date,
          ];
```

This will give you a collection with unique user, containing the related models

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` to make the query like this:

```
    $data = [
        "hourlogs"  => $hourLog
           ->select('user_id')
           ->whereBetween('date', $date)
           ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
           ->orderBy('start_time', 'asc')
           ->distinct()
           ->get(),
        "date"=> $date,
    ];
```